# Integrating Facebook Login with Firebase using Swift only loads a white screen

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to create a Facebook login integration with Firebase. Yesterday when I done it is used to work. Since yesterday, only small UI changes leaded to a blank safari controller that should be the Facebook permissions page in order to login.

I already logged in because In my Firebase console I have my Facebook user stored, so the login functionality used to work before the UI changes. I reverted the UI changes, I've reconfigured everything, cleaned the app from the device, reinstalled pods to see if there is a newer version but still can't make it.

This is the white screen I'm talking about:

[image: blank screen]

Also, the console log tells me:

> [ViewService] Failed to get remote view controller with error: Error: domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain, code=2

These are my AppDelegate methods implemented for FacebookSDK:

```
/* App Delegate */
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                          didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    return true
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
        return self.application(application,
                                open: url,
                                sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                annotation: [:])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                                 open: url,
                                                                 sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                 annotation: annotation)
}
```

And this is my IBAction for the Facebook login:

```
/* didPressFacebookLogin(_sender: Any) */
@IBAction func didPressFacebookLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    let facebookLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    facebookLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"],
                               from: self) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to login: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current() else {
            print("Failed to get access token")
            return
        }

        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login error",
                                                        message: "Something went wrong while trying to login.",
                                                        preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(okAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I was searching for that console problem that tells me that it failed to get remote view controller... Still, no idea. Anybody had this problem with Facebook?

---

UPDATE: Works on iPad with iOS 10.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating iOS to 10.3.2 fixed the issue.